# Finding sequences with noise in a string

Tags: r, pattern-recognition

So, if I have a string like `110110110`, as you can see that, the sequence `110` is continuously appearing.

Comment: You should the important parts of your code. Otherwise, we don't know the direction you're going and can't give you pertinent suggestions

Comment: Alright! I will add the code in the post. :)

Answer (score 2):

here you go

**Regex**

```
(\w{3,})\1
```

**Test string**

```
110110111
110111111
a0cc0vaaaabaaaabaaaacaa00bvw
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - 1. [0-3]   `110`
- MATCH 2

  - 1. [13-16] `111`
- MATCH 3

  - 1. [26-31] `aaaab`

demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/oB9qD2/1)

regex is based on assumptions that pattern is at least 3 char long

Comment: It will be great if you can add a nicely put code. Thanks. :)

Comment: However I am not much familiar with the code, I answered it based on the regex tag, but I'll give a try. It may take time for me to come back, meanwhile you may try to convert the same. one point which I want to add is that if you wish to match minimum 3 occurrence of the pattern the regex would be [(\w{3,})\1{2,}](http://regex101.com/r/oB9qD2/2) regex in answer is based on the test strings provided in the question.

Comment: Exactly. I was having that doubt. I want to know one more thing, do you think it takes into account the presence of noise? Because, what it is currently doing right now is matching two occurences of a pattern and then outputting them.

Comment: In the comment as well, what you have posted, it is seeing, the occurence of continuous 4 patterns in a row. I dont really want that, what I want is that the patterns are being matched but there is some noise so that is what I wish to find out.

Comment: I also uploaded the code, it is in the question edit history, maybe you can see that once, :)

Comment: the regex would match a minimum of the defined number of subsequent occurrences which is 3 or more in this regex `(\w{3,})\1{2,}` you can simply control the number of occurrence of pattern. eg regex in answer would match exactly 2 subsequent occurrence of the pattern, regex in comment would match 3 or more subsequent occurrence of the pattern. if you want just 3 subsequent occurrence then regex would be `(\w{3,})\1{2}`. last but not the least, as I told earlier that I am not much familiar with the code, so it is bit difficult for me. I am fine with with regex.

Comment: I am really sorry as I am not able to convey to you what I really want. What you have posted is, let's take this example, `abcbcdbcd` , your regex expression, the one you posted in the original answer, will output `bcd` as the answer, but it's not the answer. There is no pattern here.

Comment: What I can ask you to list the possible inputs and outputs which can cover most of the possible scenarios. let's refine the regex to match the desired result.